# Is Python3 shlex.quote() safe?

Tags: bash, python-3.x, security, escaping

I execute some code in shell using

```
subprocess.Popen('echo '+user_string+' | pipe to some string manipulation tools',
    shell=True)
```

where user_string is from an untrusted source.

Is it safe enough to use `shlex.quote()` for escaping the input?

Comment: Perhaps your code is simplified from a more complex example, but simply piping the input to `pipe` here is superior in every way to having the shell `echo` a quoted representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [official pyton documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) for `shlex.quote` the answer is yes.

Of course that also depends on what you mean by "safe enough". Under the assumption that you mean "Will using `shlex.quote` on `user_string` guard me against a typical scenario of malicious shell code passed as string input to my script?" the answer is yes.

Answer (score 5):

I'm necromancing this because it's the top Google hit for "is shlex.quote() safe", and while the accepted answer seems correct, there's a lot of pitfalls to point out.

`shlex.quote()` escapes the shell's parsing, but it does not escape the argument parser of the command you're calling, and some additional tool-specific escaping needs to be done manually, especially if your string starts with a dash (`-`).

**Most** (but not all) tools accept `--` as an argument, and anything afterward is interpreted as verbatim. You can prepend `"-- "` if the string starts with `"-"`. Example: `rm -- --help` removes the file called `--help`.

When dealing with file names, you can prepend `"./"` if the string starts with `"-"`: `rm ./--help`.

In the case of your example with `echo`, neither escape is sufficient: When attempting to echo the string `-e`, `echo -- -e` gives the wrong result, you'll need something like `echo -e \x2de`. This demonstrates that there's no universal bulletproof way to escape program arguments.

The safest route is to bypass the shell by **avoiding** `shell=True` or `os.system()` if the string involves any user-supplied data.

In your case, set `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` and pass the `user_string` as an argument to `communicate()`. Then you can even leave your original invocation as-is with `shell=True`:

```
subprocess.Popen(
    'pipe to some string manipulation tools',
    shell=True,
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE
).communicate(user_input_string.encode())
```